# Basics of coding for numericupdown for C# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, numericupdown

I'm creating a program to let user interact with their customers when they are buying their food (Picture in link provided for more information) and I'm trying to use NumericUpDown control for the first time so I have no idea how to do the coding for this control . Can anyone tell me the basics for the coding of numericupdown control so that when I click "Total" , it shows the correct price when tallied with the amount of prata/addon in the numericupdown control . I tried googling for a guide on how to do the coding for numericupdown but I can't find anything so if someone knows of a website on numericupdown control tutorial please let me know !

Just to be clear : What I'm asking for is to show me the basics for the coding of one numbericupdown control so that I can figure out the rest and do it by myself :)

This is the image : http://postimg.org/image/ygat3ax9r/

I'm new here so if I made any mistakes please let me know !
Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: The basics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nudThing.Value` will get the value of the control which you can add up. But you should really get familiar with the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as Savanna pointed out, for future reference.